# Как написать код акции с изменением переменной каждые 4 дня?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите написать код акции Есть день например сегодня 15, акция до 19 числа, 16 числа тоже 19, но когда наступает 19 число, то акция меняется до 23, то есть каждые 4 дня меняется число в блоке, как решить?
Понимаю что примерно так, но дальше ничего в голову не лезет(

```
var date = new Date();
var target = 15;
var now = date.getDate();

if (now === target) {
// do something
target += 4; 
}
```

Comment: Посчитать количество дней до нулевой точки, разделить нацело на 4, прибавить единицу, умножить на 4.

Comment: Если я верно понял вопрос, то вас где-то есть 19 число, которое должно браться откуда-то, или же должна быть отправная точка, например начало месяца, не до конца понятен этот момент. Поясните, откуда берутся эти данные из базы или же по какому-то алгоритму?

Comment: Sergey Glazirin Я сам еще не совсем понимаю как и куда  двигаться дальше, лучше писать алгоритм, так как базу данных надо будет еще подключать)

Comment: etki можно пример? а то так не совсем понятно будут ли даты меняться или они будут статичны)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял формулировку, то:

- Есть некий текст вывода вроде "Акция длится до ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"
- Нужно выводить ДД.ММ.ГГ такими, что до конца акции всегда остается от 4 до 1 дня, но когда эта дата приходит - продлевать акцию на 4 дня

В итоге пользователь всегда будет видеть "горячую акцию", до конца которой осталось менее 4 дней, но явного обмана не будет - в пределах 4 дней акция до одного и того же числа

Открываем [описание класса Javascript Date()](http://javascript.ru/Date) в любом гугле

Для простоты будем использовать номер дня в месяце `getDate()` (не самое очевидное название) за старт акции (то есть с 1 по 4 число, с 5 по 9, с 10 по 14 и так далее)

Есть текущая дата. Нам нужно узнать, когда при текущей дате "закончится" акция. Очевидно, что в следущий день, (номер-1) которого будет нацело делиться на 4. Минус один потому что нумерация дней начинается с 1, а числа в математике начинаются с 0.

```
/* Текущая дата и время */
var now = new Date();
/* Для отладки вы можете использовать не сегодняшнюю дату, а пример ниже */
// now = new Date(2017,4,14,2,31,30);
alert('Сегодня '+now.toLocaleString());
/* До тех пор, пока (номер дня - 1) не делится нацело на 4, прибавляем 1 день к дате */
while ((now.getDate()-1) % 4 != 0) {
    now.setDate(now.getDate()+1);
}
alert('Акция закончится '+now.toLocaleString());
```

Более "страшный" вариант, но более надежный - считать в секундах от начала эпохи:

```
/* Текущая дата и время */
var now = new Date();
alert('Сегодня '+now.toLocaleString());
/* До тех пор, пока (номер дня - 1) не делится нацело на 4, прибавляем 1 день к дате */
var one_day = 1*24*60*60*1000; // Один день в миллисекундах
var period = 4*24*60*60*1000; // Период обновления акции в миллисекунды
// Прежде чем двигать время, надо округлить до целых суток, иначе имеем бесконечный цикл
now.setTime(now.getTime() - now.getTime() % one_day);
while ((now.getTime() % period) != 0) {
    now.setTime(now.getTime()+one_day);
}
alert('Акция закончится '+now.toLocaleString());
```

Логика та же самая, только блок 4 дня переводится в секунды. Тонкости - временная зона

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Если я правильно понял, сейчас показывается, что акция закончиться 17 числа, после наступления 17 числа будет +4 дня то есть 21 число?

Comment: Ну сделайте присвоение `now = new Date(2018,1,18,2,31,30);` в первом примере и посмотрите сами

Comment: На самом деле первый пример плохой ) Там зарыта ошибка при переходе через месяц. Но это просто чтобы понять логику решения. Я вам советую понять логику на первом примере и сразу переходить в реализации на второй пример, дорабатывая его

Comment: Хорошо! Я понял, спасибо за помощь!